# Equation of a parabola-shaped toroidal tube with circular cross-sections

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections, 3d, surfaces

I need an implicit function that plots the surface that I am showing you in the picture. Everything you need is shown there. The surface is a tube in the shape of a parabola. The radius of its cross-sections is $3$.

[image: parabola]

Comment: Do you mean that it should be a parabolic tube with  a circular cross-section of radius 3?

Comment: I found a way. (0.75-sqrt(y^2+z^2/3))^2+x^2<0.030 gives me a parabolic tube with enough radius. Now I should rotate it by 45 degrees. Any hint?

Comment: Hi TyTiKi; What software did you use?

Comment: A parabola shaped toroidal tube. If not ok, I can put back old title before edit.

Answer (score 0):

Rotating can be done by a "simple" substitution of variables.

This was just wrong! <strike>Rotating 45 degrees around the $z$-axis is done by replacing:
$x$ with $\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)}$ and
$y$ with $\sqrt{(x^2-y^2)}$
(that might be 45 degrees in the wrong direction for your case, but in that case swap $+$ and $-$).</strike>

The substitution should describe the inverse transformation of what you want (you can do much more than rotations with variable substitutions), so for a rotation of 45 degrees around the $z$-axis is (I hope I get it right this time):
$x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}x-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}y$ and
$y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}x+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}y$.
$\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}=\cos(\frac{\pi}{2})=\sin(\frac{\pi}{2})\right)$

It won't make your equation any prettier though...